# Access variable inside function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How can I access a variable `name` inside an input box?

```js
'use strict';

app.controller('myDummyController', function($scope){
    console.log("I am in controller");

    $scope.myd = function() {
        $scope.name = "prashannt";
    }
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="myDummyController">
    <input ng-controller="myd"> </input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-model is the way

```
<form ng-controller="myDummyController" ng-submit="myd">
    <input ng-model="name" type="text"/> Input value is {{name}}
    <button type="submit">click me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you're welcome, its all written in the official documentation ;)

Answer (score 0):

first you have to define what is app..!!

```
var app=angular.module("myapp",[]); // app is defined here
    app.controller('myDummyController', function($scope){
    console.log("I am in controller");

 $scope.myd="prashant";
});


<body ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="myDummyController">

        <input ng-model="myd"> </input>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I hope you get it